# Prism : Register region in another window than shell

Tags: c#, wpf, prism-6, prism-7

I'm building a project with Prism and I was wondering if there is a way to have region from another window than the shell registred in the region manager.

The control i try to build has to be in a separate window, and it would be nice to have region in this new window to inject several views.

Thanks !

Answer (score -2):

You basically can define a region everywhere. Define a **Region** for a View and withhin this View you can defina another **Region**.

```
<!--Main Window-->
xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/" 

<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Content Grid.Column="0" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion1"/> 'Injects View1
<Content Grid.Column="1" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion2"/>
<Grid>

<!--View1 in MainRegion1-->
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Content Grid.Column="0" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="SubRegion1"/>
<Content Grid.Column="1" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="SubRegion2"/>
<Grid>
```